# Apache Beam pipeline with FlinkRunner grow side input size when recovering from a checkpoint/savepoint untill OOM

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

We are using **Flink runner** **1.15** to launch streaming pipelines written using **Apache Beam 2.45**.

For the state backend we use `HashMapStateBackend` and checkpoints are saved to HDFS.
Unaligned checkpoints are disabled and the pipeline checkpoints every 15 minutes.

The topology uses quite a lot of side inputs to enrich the main source - Kafka topic.
Each side input is configured in a similar way. The side input reads the state once
on the initial startup into a default global window and never updates it.

Here is code to create a view from files on HDFS

```java
Pipeline pipeline = ...;

PCollectionView<LookupState> view = pipeline
        .apply(new ReadAvroFileFromHdfs(pipeline.getOptions()))
        .apply(View.asSingleton());
```

We create many views and perform lookups in a single transform.

The problematic part of the pipeline is on the picture below. There are 6 side inputs - with a broadcast title on the arrow.
On the top left side there is a Kafka source (KafkaIO) that is forwarding records
to the enrichment operator (bottom-left square), which has 1 main input from Kafka and 6 side inputs.
[image: flink-topology]

Initial launch of the pipeline checkpoints state of a constant size that never increases.
In case of a failure or a graceful restart, the pipeline starts from the last valid checkpoint.
After a restart we observe growth of checkpoint size.
The enrichment operator state randomly multiplies 2x or 3x or 4x from the one in checkpoint, while the others don't. This issue is triggered, when parallelism is greater than 1, in this example it's 4.

On the graph below you can see change of the checkpoint size. Each change corresponds to a restart.
When the size decreases, it means that the pipeline was started without initial state, because the pipeline fails with OOM error and cannot recover.[image: checkpoint-size]

I checked the heap dump and I can see that the side input state has the same lookup object, produced by the view, multiple times, even though the side input is not read again on the startup.

1. Is it a known bug in Flink/Beam?
2. Does anyone know how this problem could investigated further?

As an experiment I changed the code to refresh side inputs according to the [Slowly updating global window side input pattern](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/#slowly-updating-global-window-side-inputs) and I observed that the refresh resets the state to the initial size, however, it's not feasible to refresh state often and it could not be used as a solution to the problem.

I expect that after a restore from a checkpoint, next checkpoints won't multiply their size, assuming there is no any load on the pipeline.